# Find folders called SS, return size of folder

Tags: command-line, powershell, dir

I am able to find all folders called "SS" (superseded) in a hierarchy and list out the location of each one.

I have been using this code to pipe out the list.

DIR /AD /B "SS" /S > SS_Folder_List.txt

How can I use either Powershell or the Command Line to take this list and return the total size of each folder?

Comment: What have you tried already? Where exactly are you getting stuck writing the script?

Comment: The above script works, I would like to know how to complete a further step. It returns a list of folders, how can I get the output to include the size of these listed folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in a single command:

```
for /d /r %%d in (ss.?) do dir "%%d" | Find "File(s)"
```

Some notes:

- Your system needs to be in English, otherwise change **File(s)** to whatever your system outputs to the dir command
- The for loop needs a wildcard, hence **ss.?** So, if you have folders called for instance **ss.s** these will also be included
- If run from a command line, use %d instead of %%d

Comment: works brilliantly. I piped the output to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

according to the first solution in [How to list all folder with size via batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711180/how-to-list-all-folder-with-size-via-batch-file) your answer would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "folder=ss%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    set "size=0"
    for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "size=%%~b"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo(%folder%\%%~nxa Size = !size!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
```